# "This is not always used." vs. "This is not used very often."

Tags: grammar, meaning

Are the above sentences interchangeable?

Do they have the same meaning or there is a little difference between them?

What is the most common way?

Answer (score 3):

```
Are the above sentences interchangeable?
```

Definitely not.

I would use *"This is not always used."* when talking about something that is almost ***always*** used, but not always.

I would use *"This is not used very often."* when talking about something that is almost ***never*** used, but is used sometimes.